# Getting form values

Tags: angularjs

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.checkVal = function () {
            console.log('entered');
            console.log($scope.data.user)
        }

        $scope.data = {
            //to keep the data from the api or any static data
            //this will used to show the data in the view
            user: {
                fname: '',
                lname: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }

        };
        $scope.methods = {
            //this will called from the views to interact with properties and data
            //use methods to change the values 
            checkVal: function () {
                console.log('entered');
                console.log($scope.data.user)
            },
        };
        $scope.properties = {
            //only to change views for ng-if and ng-show
        }

}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div action="#" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
        <div id="modal-login" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form action="#home" ng-submit="ctrl.methods.checkVal()">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input ng-model="ctrl.data.user.email" type="text" name="user-email" placeholder="Email:" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input ng-model="ctrl.data.user.password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" required>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="form-group clearfix">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I am trying to insert the values from the form in the object that i created in the controller. But somehow it isn't doing that. I don't understand why the data binding of this form doesn't give the output in the console like i asked it to. What am i doing wrong?

**html**

```
<body>
<div action="#" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    <div id="modal-login" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="#home" ng-submit="ctrl.methods.checkVal()">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input ng-model="ctrl.data.user.email" type="text" name="user-email" placeholder="Email:" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input ng-model="ctrl.data.user.password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" required>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.checkVal = function () {
        console.log('entered');
        console.log($scope.data.user)
    }

    $scope.data = {
        //to keep the data from the api or any static data
        //this will used to show the data in the view
        user: {
            fname: '',
            lname: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }

    };
    $scope.methods = {
        //this will called from the views to interact with properties and data
        //use methods to change the values 
        checkVal: function () {
            console.log('entered');
            console.log($scope.data.user)
        },
    };
    $scope.properties = {
        //only to change views for ng-if and ng-show
    }
```

}])

Answer (score 1):

becaues you use controllerAs in view you must use this format

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var vm = this;
vm.checkVal = function () {
    console.log('entered');
    console.log($scope.data.user)
}

vm.data = {
    //to keep the data from the api or any static data
    //this will used to show the data in the view
    user: {
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }

};
vm.methods = {
    //this will called from the views to interact with properties and data
    //use methods to change the values 
    checkVal: function () {
        console.log('entered');
        console.log($scope.data.user)
    },
};
vm.properties = {
    //only to change views for ng-if and ng-show
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
[JSFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/17b7bqk1/)

```
<script>
    angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.checkVal = function () {
            console.log('entered');
            console.log($scope.data.user)
        }

        $scope.data = {
            //to keep the data from the api or any static data
            //this will used to show the data in the view
            user: {
                fname: '',
                lname: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }

        };
        $scope.methods = {
            //this will called from the views to interact with properties and data
            //use methods to change the values 
            checkVal: function (ctrl) {
                console.log('entered');
                console.log(ctrl)
            },
        };
        $scope.properties = {
            //only to change views for ng-if and ng-show
        }
    }])
</script>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div action="#" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
        <div id="modal-login" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form ng-submit="methods.checkVal(data)">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input ng-model="data.user.email" type="text" name="user-email" placeholder="Email:" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input ng-model="data.user.password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password:" required>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="form-group clearfix">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```